# ETIMEDOUT on q-io/http.request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, q

Using q-io/http to pull in a web page is failing. I think I must be missing something obvious - because this is what I think is a pretty straight forward example.

Edit: windows 8, node 11.13

```
var http = require('q-io/http')

var url =  'http://www.google.com' ;
http.request({
    method: 'GET',
    uri: url
}).
then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
}).
fail(function (err) {
    console.error(err)
});
```

Here is the output:

```
{ state: 'pending' }
> { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT]
  stack: 'Error: connect ETIMEDOUT\n    at exports._errnoException (util.js:742:11)\n    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:989:19)',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

This is slightly different than the duplicate.  q-io/http will close the request AFTER you read the body.  Reading the body looks to be essential here.

Comment: Are you positive - it looks like the request is closed inside of q-io/http

Comment: sorry, when searching for the error message I confused the modules. You're not using `request`. Still, the reason is probably similar :-)

Comment: I have the answer - but essentially you need to read the body of the q-io/http request at which point it will end the request (like in the referenced post)

Comment: Then you should [answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :-)

Comment: Thanks for unlocking it.  I will get  the answer up there this evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well changing the code to this:

```
var http = require('q-io/http')

var url =  'http://www.google.com' ;

results = qHttp.request({ url: url }).then(function(res){
    return res.body.read().then(function(bodyStream){
        var body = bodyStream.toString('UTF-8')
        return body
    })
})
```

accessing the response body looks to solve the problem, my assumption is that the stream is getting closed within the confines of q-io/http (which is wrapping the Node/http library).  I spent some time tracing the code - but cannot find the exact path to the .end()